# Obj-C - Embed YouTube video in UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, youtube, uiwebview

I'm using the below code to try and have a youtube video play inside my app (in a UIWebView). For some reason, my WebView returns as just a black box, and no video plays.

**See below:**

**DashboardViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSString *videoURL = @"https://youtu.be/8QrCPihtBSc";


    UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.howtoView.frame.size.width, self.howtoView.frame.size.height)];
    self.howtoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.howtoView.opaque = NO;
    self.howtoView.delegate = self;
    [self.howtoView addSubview:videoView];


    NSString *videoHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                 <html>\
                 <head>\
                 <style type=\"text/css\">\
                 iframe {position:absolute; top:50%%; margin-top:-130px;}\
                 body {background-color:#000; margin:0;}\
                 </style>\
                 </head>\
                 <body>\
                 <iframe width=\"100%%\" height=\"240px\" src=\"%@\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>\
                 </body>\
                 </html>", videoURL];

    [videoView loadHTMLString:videoHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. UIWebView is already deprecated, please us WKWebView
2. There is `embed` button on youtube web page, that gives you required code.